# How to detect .env file changes during a process, instantly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, environment-variables, window

I am writing an Electron application. I'm using HTML + CSS + JAVASCRIPT with Electron. As you can see below, I have a form and I keep this form information in an .env file. I start the Electron application, open and fill the form, and then save it to the .env file. Thus, my .env file is changed, but I cannot immediately recognize the changes in my .env file. Therefore, if I open my form again, old information is coming. If I restart my Electron application, this event is fixed. How can i solve this problem? I would appreciate your help, my dear developer friends.
[First situation: Before I don't save informations to .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PydgS.png)
[Second situation: Saved time view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHEjC.png)
I'm reopen settings window and last result (It gets old information but .env file changed)
[Last situation: As you can see...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ZQm.png)

I'm try app.relaunch()  method on this situation. But nothing affect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to detect changes to a .env file during a process in real-time:

File System Watcher: You can use the watch command in Linux or the fs.watch method in Node.js to watch for changes to a specific file or directory. This method will trigger a callback function whenever the .env file is modified.

Polling: You can use a setInterval or setTimeout function to periodically check the .env file for changes. This method will trigger a callback function if the .env file has been modified since the last check.

Event-driven: You can use an event-driven approach to detect changes to the .env file. This method will trigger a callback function whenever the .env file is modified.

Use a library: There are several libraries available that can be used to detect changes in the .env file like dotenv-expand, dotenv-webpack and etc.

You should choose the method that best suits your specific use case and programming language.

Please keep in mind that the above methods are general suggestions and you may need to make some adjustments depending on your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ankit Jain.  I have been detect .env file changes like this                               (async () => {
  const watcher = fs.watch('../.env');
  watcher.on('change', () => {
    console.log('.env changed')
    shell.beep()

  });
})();  But I'm trying get .env changes informations (new informations) in during procces (without run this npm script:  npm run dev. How can do this ?

Comment: This answer was generated by ChaptGPT.